# Check whether link's text is "B" then remove its class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check whether an `a` node contains the word "B". If so, the node's `someclass` class should be removed.

For example:

```
<a href="http://link.com" class="someclass">B</a>
```

Comment: Should the link text equal 'B' or just contain it, i.e. 'A B C' would also need to changed?

Comment: What did you try? And what do you mean by "word"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("a:contains('B')").removeClass('someclass');
```

Comment: `<a href="http://link.com" class="someclass">Bring longer words to this party please</a>`

Comment: Glad to help, Edward. If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the tick below the vote counts on the left hand side of my answer. 
@Tomalak Geret'kal: I see where you are going, but it's for context. I suffer from premature optimization, trying to think of all the complexities, too. However, sometimes it's just acceptable to work within the boundaries you think you will face on that specific context.

Comment: @Shef: The OP specifically said `contains the word "B"`. Your answer does not meet that specification.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Bring on your regex, then.

Comment: Not until @edward actually tells us what he _really_ means by "word".

Comment: Yes , this is the answer i'm looking for . thanks for those who helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){

   var text = $(this).text();

   if(text.indexOf("B")>= 0 ) {

         $(this).removClass('someclass');
   }

});
```